# How to identify the digit 7 between the given number

Tags: c

I want my code to print "YES" if there is digit 7 in the entered number, and otherwise print "NO".

When I use `while(T != 0)` for test cases, my code prints "YES" for all the numbers - even for number 45. Without `while(T != 0)` my code runs perfectly.

Where is my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    while (T != 0) {
        int X;
        scanf("%d", &X);
        int flag, result;

        while (X != 0) {
            result = X % 10;

            if (result == 7) {
                flag = 1;
            }

            X = X / 10;
        }

        if (flag == 1) {
            puts("YES");
        } else {
            puts("NO");
        }

        T--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try initialising `flag = 0;` Don't use uninitialised variables.

Comment: Wouldn't a simpler predicate be `x >= 1000000 && x < 10000000`?

Comment: @Neil The example is checking if given numbers 'contain' the digit 7, not that they are 7-digit numbers.

Comment: My misunderstanding. You don't need to check further (`flag`) once it found one (short-circuit evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

After trying out your code, the main issue was not with the "while" test.  Rather, in the code your test flag was not being reset so once the a value was found to have the digit "7" in it, all subsequent tests were noted as being "YES".  With that, following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int T;
    printf("How many numbers to test: ");           /* Clarifies what the user is being asked for */
    scanf("%d", &T);

    while (T != 0)
    {
        int X;
        printf("Enter a number to be tested: ");    /* Again, lets the user know what to enter */
        scanf("%d", &X);
        int flag = 0, result;

        while (X != 0)
        {
            result = X % 10;

            if (result == 7)
            {
                flag = 1;
            }

            X = X / 10;
        }

        if (flag == 1)
        {
            puts("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            puts("NO");
        }
        flag = 0;   /* Needs to be reset after being set and before next check */

        T--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Some things to note.

- Although not really needed, verbiage was added as prompts to clarify to the user what needed to be entered for values.
- Most importantly, the flag variable gets initialized to zero and then subsequently gets reset to zero after each test has been completed.

With those bits addressed, following is some sample terminal output.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Seven/bin/Release$ ./Seven 
How many numbers to test: 4
Enter a number to be tested: 3987
YES
Enter a number to be tested: 893445
NO
Enter a number to be tested: 8445
NO
Enter a number to be tested: 58047
YES
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: yeah i got the answer .But why we want to initialize flag as 0

Comment: What you are describing is one possible outcome of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). In the original example, when defined, `int flag;` lacks initialization, and thus contains an *indeterminate* value. The object in question may occupy the same memory space as previous iteration, which *might* give the appearance of the value not being 'reset', but again, this is UB. The fix in your code is the initialization. 'Resetting' the value is misleading, as its [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) ends when the block finishes executing.